# Достать значение из numericUpDown которые находятся в списке List<Controls>

Tags: c#, wpf

```
     List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();

        controls.Add(d1); controls.Add(d2);
        controls.Add(d3); controls.Add(d4);
        controls.Add(d5); controls.Add(d6);
        controls.Add(d7); controls.Add(d8);
        controls.Add(d9); controls.Add(d10);
        controls.Add(d11); controls.Add(d12);
        controls.Add(d13); controls.Add(d14);
        controls.Add(d15); controls.Add(d16);
        controls.Add(d17); controls.Add(d18);
        controls.Add(d19); controls.Add(d20);
        controls.Add(d21); controls.Add(d22);
        controls.Add(d23); controls.Add(d24);
        controls.Add(d25); controls.Add(d26);
        controls.Add(d27); controls.Add(d28);
```

В списке 28 элементов типа

```
<xctk:IntegerUpDown Name="d1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"   FontSize="14"/>
```

как достать значения из списка  а именно d1.value; d2.value; и т.д

Comment: Жесть, не пробовали привязки? ItemsControl? Вот это все.

Comment: @Андрей NOP быть может человек только учится, зачем вы так сразу? Я бы попросил автора рассказать, какую именно задачу он решает, так как решение сделано "в лоб" и вероятно его можно улучшить. И что такое `value` у контрола.

Comment: @aepot Не соглашусь с вами, ибо если есть возможность, то лучше человека направить сразу в нужное направление и указать на его неточность, ибо потом он подобный подход будет воспринимать как эталонным и единственно верным. Я изначально писал примерно также, как и автор данного вопроса и до сих пор рад тому, что меня один человек направил в нужное русло, без него бы я думал бы, что привязки в WPF - неведомая магия, которая мне не нужна. Так что мы тут в какой то степени учим людей, а учить надо правильным вещам. P.S. Оповещение @ вроде не работает, если ник идет через пробел, пишите слитно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не стал делать 28, а всего 3, вот такая разметка

```
<Grid x:Name="_grid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <xctk:IntegerUpDown x:Name="_iUpDown1" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <xctk:IntegerUpDown x:Name="_iUpDown2" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <xctk:IntegerUpDown x:Name="_iUpDown3" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <Button x:Name="_button"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Content="OK"/>
</Grid>
```

Тогда код такой

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _button.Click += Button_Click;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //cоздаем словарь в качестве ключа -> имя IntegerUpDown
        Dictionary<string, int?> values = _grid.Children.OfType<IntegerUpDown>()
                                                        .ToDictionary(i => i.Name, i => i.Value);

        //достаем значение по имени нужного IntegerUpDown
        int value = values["_iUpDown2"] ?? 0;
    }
}
```